# Is it more effective to aim for the head in Day of Defeat:Source?

Tags: day-of-defeat-source

I've been playing DoD:S for a couple of months and I have been wondering if it's more effective to shoot people in the head rather than just mindlessly aiming at them.

Also besides the head, is there another vital area I should be aiming for as a plan B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first answer was not entirely correct, after some more research I found this page, with some hard numbers:

http://www.d3scene.com/forum/other-games/18935-dod-source-weapon-guide.html

Here is seems like there is headshot dmg and body dmg.

Eg. for the K98K:

Damage Per Headshot: 275

Body Hit Damage: 110